# Unable to import tensorflow (using pycharm IDE)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, import, tensorflow

I have installed everything and setup all dependencies for Tensorflow in Ubuntu.

But after running it, it shows this error:

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Have you searched for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it was an interpreter issue. I have managed to change default interpreter for this project in **Project Preferences** > **Project Interpreter**

Then, I've changed the interpreter to where i am installing the tensorflow and issue is now resolved.